# bulk user import for joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, import, bulk

can someone help me with this php-script, this script is for Joomla 1.5 and I am using 2.5. This is not compatible and I am confused of the tables used because 1.5 and 2.5 has different table names. some tables in 1.5 are not also in 2.5

btw, this script is a bulk user import using csv file to sql/database.

```
<?php

// Hande form upload
if(isset($_POST['import'])) {

    $mysql_host             = trim($_POST['mysql_host']);
    $mysql_user             = trim($_POST['mysql_username']);
    $mysql_password         = trim($_POST['mysql_password']);
    $mysql_schema           = trim($_POST['mysql_schema']);

    $table_prefix           = trim($_POST['table_prefix']);

    if(!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_schema)) {
        echo 'Supplied MySQL details were incorrect - aborting';
        return;
    }


    // Get the joomla groups
    $sql = sprintf('
            SELECT  `id`, `value`
            FROM    `%score_acl_aro_groups`
        ', 
        $table_prefix
    );
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    $groups = array();
    while($group = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $groups[$group->value] = $group->id;
    }


    $fp = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    while($user = fgetcsv($fp)) {

        printf('Importing "%s" ... ', $user[0]);

        // Lookup and verify user group
        if(!isset($groups[$user[4]])) {
            printf('error: Invalid group (%s) for %s. Defaulting to <code>Registered</code><br />%s', $user[4], $user[0], PHP_EOL);
            $user[4] = 'Registered';
        }

        // Insert record into wsers
        $sql = sprintf('
            INSERT INTO `%susers` 
            SET
                `name`            = "%s",
                `username`        = "%s",
                `email`           = "%s",
                `password`        = "%s",
                `usertype`        = "%s",
                `block`           = "%s",
                `sendEmail`       = "%s",
                `gid`             = "%s",
                `registerDate`    = NOW(),
                `lastvisitDate`   = "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                `activation`      = "",
                `params`          = ""
            ',
            $table_prefix,
            sql_prep($user[0]),
            sql_prep($user[1]),
            sql_prep($user[2]),
            isset($_POST['md5_passwords']) ? md5($user[3]) : sql_prep($user[3]),
            sql_prep($user[4]),
            sql_prep($user[5]),
            sql_prep($user[6]),
            $groups[$user[4]]
        );
        mysql_query($sql);
        // Get back ther user's ID
        list($user_id) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'));

        // Insert record into core_acl_aro
        $sql = sprintf('
                INSERT INTO `%score_acl_aro`
                SET
                    `section_value`   = "users",
                    `value`           = %d,
                    `name`            = "%s"
            ',
            $table_prefix,
            $user_id,
            sql_prep($user[0])
        );
        mysql_query($sql);

        // Insert record into core_acl_groups_aro_map
        $sql = sprintf('
                INSERT INTO `%score_acl_groups_aro_map`
                SET
                    `group_id`        = %d,
                    `aro_id`          = LAST_INSERT_ID()
            ',
            $table_prefix,
            $groups[$user[4]]
        );
        mysql_query($sql);

        echo 'done.';
        flush();
    }

    echo '<br /><br /><strong>Done</strong>';


} else {
    // show upload form
    ?>
    <html><head><title>Bulk import users into Joomla 1.5</title></head><body>
    <h1>Import Users to Joomla</h1>
    <p>
        Use this script to do a bulk import of users into Joomla 1.5.<br />
        Upload a CSV file with the following format:<br />
        <code>
            name, username, email, password, usertype, block, send_email
        </code><br />
        Wrap details with commas in them in quotes.
    </p>
    <hr />
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="import" value="1" />
        <table cellpadding="4px">
            <tr>
                <td>CSV File: </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="csv" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MD5 Hash Passwords: </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="md5_passwords" /><br /><small>*Check this option if the passwords in your CSV are in plain text</small></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joomla Table Prefix: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="table_prefix" value="jos_" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joomla Database Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_schema" value="joomla" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MySQL Host: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_host" value="localhost" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MySQL Username: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_username" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MySQL Password: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_password" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Import Users! " /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body></html>
    <?php
}

function sql_prep($var) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this CLI application](https://github.com/elinw/AddUsersFromTable) for bulk import from a table in the same database, you could adapt it to import from your CSV or you could import the CSV file into a database table. Anyway it will get you started, the whole thing is really different than 1.5.

Comment: hi Elin. I am beginner. I don't know where to put the code. I hope you could help me. I'm very desperate right now. thank you! :)

Comment: TO use my script as is you would need to put the user data into a table called #__user_import with the same field names for the matching fields as #__users (name, username, password etc). Put the script in the cli folder of your Joomla instance. Then at the command line type php addusers.php.

https://github.com/elinw/AddUsersFromTable/blob/master/AddUsersFromTable.php#L14

Comment: Honestly though, there are a bunch of extensions on the jed to help you with this.

Comment: I did found one but its on the backend in Joomla. I need it to the frontend. thats why I am so troubled.

Comment: Joomla does not do any user management from the frontend at this time.  you might be able to use a CRM application but most of those will probably be back end for adminstrative tasks. What you say makes no sense anyway, how would you have used that old script from the front end in 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the right code for bulk user upload in Joomla 3.
So I reworked the code to work with the new database structure.

It works starting with a simple CSV file:

```
    <?php

// Hande form upload
if(isset($_POST['import'])) 
    {

    $mysql_host             = trim($_POST['mysql_host']);
    $mysql_user             = trim($_POST['mysql_username']);
    $mysql_password         = trim($_POST['mysql_password']);
    $mysql_schema           = trim($_POST['mysql_schema']);
    $table_prefix           = trim($_POST['table_prefix']);


    if(!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_schema)) {
        echo 'Supplied MySQL details were incorrect - aborting';
        return;
        }

        // set tablenames
        $tb_users = $table_prefix . 'users';
        $tb_usergroups = $table_prefix . 'usergroups';
        $tb_user_usergroup_map = $table_prefix . 'user_usergroup_map';

        // open cvs file
        $fp = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], 'r');

        // validate data
        $valid_data = true;
        while($user = fgetcsv($fp)) {

            // Verify name
            if(!isset($user[0])) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid Name </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            } elseif($user[0] == '') {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid Name </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            }

            // Verify username
            if(!isset($user[1])) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid username </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            } elseif($user[1] == '') {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid username </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            }

            // Verify email
            if(!isset($user[2])) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid email </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            } elseif($user[2] == '') {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid email </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            }

            // Verify Password
            if(!isset($user[3])) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid password </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            } elseif($user[3] == '') {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid password </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            }

            // Verify usergroup
            if(!isset($user[4])) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid usergroup </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            } elseif($user[4] == '') {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Invalid usergroup </strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_data = false;
            }

            // Check duplicate username
            $sql = '
                    SELECT COUNT(*) AS duplicate_username
                    FROM    '.$tb_users.'
                    WHERE   username = "'.$user[1].'"'; 

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $duplicate_users = $row['duplicate_username'];
            }

            if ($duplicate_users > 0) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Duplicate username </strong><br />', $user);
                    $valid_data = false;
            }

            // Check duplicate email
            $sql = '
                    SELECT COUNT(*) AS duplicate_email
                    FROM    '.$tb_users.'
                    WHERE   email = "'.$user[2].'"'; 

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $duplicate_users = $row['duplicate_email'];
            }

            if ($duplicate_users > 0) {
                display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Duplicate email </strong><br />', $user);
                    $valid_data = false;
            }

    }


    if(!$valid_data) {
        die('<strong>CSV file contains errors. Upload Aborted!</strong>');
    } else {
        printf('<strong>Data is valid. Uploading users...</strong><br />');
    }


    // Count initial users
    $sql = '
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS initial_users
            FROM    '.$tb_users.'
           '
        ; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $initial_users = $row['initial_users'];
    }



    // Load users

    // open cvs file
    $fp = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], 'r');

    $counter = 0;
    while($user = fgetcsv($fp)) {


        // Check duplicate username
        $valid_username = true;
        $sql = '
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS duplicate_username
                FROM    '.$tb_users.'
                WHERE   username = "'.$user[1].'"'; 

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $duplicate_username = $row['duplicate_username'];
        }

        if ($duplicate_users > 0) {
            display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Duplicate username found in database</strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_username = false;
        }

        // Check duplicate email
        $valid_mail = true;
        $sql = '
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS duplicate_email
                FROM    '.$tb_users.'
                WHERE   email = "'.$user[2].'"'; 

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $duplicate_users = $row['duplicate_email'];
        }

        if ($duplicate_users > 0) {
            display_user('<br /><strong>ERROR!!! Duplicate email found in database</strong><br />', $user);
                $valid_mail = false;
        }

        if(!$valid_username or !$valid_mail) {
            printf('<strong>WARNING!!! User not uploaded</strong><br /><br />');
        } else {

            // Upload user
            display_user('<br />', $user);


            // Encypt password if required      
            $user_password = isset($_POST['md5_passwords']) ? md5($user[3]) : sql_prep($user[3]);

            // Insert record into users
            $sql = "
                INSERT INTO ".$tb_users." 
                SET
                    name            = '".sql_prep($user[0])."',
                    username        = '".sql_prep($user[1])."',
                    email           = '".sql_prep($user[2])."',
                    password        = '".$user_password."',
                    registerDate    = NOW(),
                    activation      = '',
                    params          = '{\"admin_style\":\"\",\"admin_language\":\"\",\"language\":\"\",\"editor\":\"\",\"helpsite\":\"\",\"timezone\":\"\"}',
                    otpKey          = '',
                    otep            = ''                
            ";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }

           // Retrieve last uploaded user's ID
            list($user_id) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'));

            printf('Assigned user ID: '.$user_id.'<br />');


            // Insert record user_group_map
            $sql = '
                    INSERT INTO '.$tb_user_usergroup_map.'
                    SET
                        user_id   = '.$user_id.',
                        group_id  = '.$user[4].'
                   ';

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }

            echo 'done.<br />';
            flush();

        }

        // Update counter
        $counter++;

    }

    // Count final users
    $sql = '
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS final_users
            FROM    '.$tb_users.'
           '
        ; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $final_users = $row['final_users'];
    }


    if(($final_users - $initial_users) == $counter) {
        echo '<br /><br /><strong>Done. <br />
              Uploaded '.$counter.' users </strong>';
    } else {
        echo '<br /><br /><strong>ERROR!!! <br />
              Uploaded only some users</strong><br />
              Users submitted: '.$counter.'<br />
              Users uploaded : '.($final_users - $initial_users);
    }


} else {

    // show upload form
    ?>
    <html><head><title>Bulk import users into Joomla 3</title></head><body>
    <h1>Import Users to Joomla</h1>
    <p>
        Use this script to do a bulk import of users into Joomla 1.5.<br />
        Upload a CSV file with the following format:<br />
        <code>
            name, username, email, password, group_number
        </code><br />
        Wrap details with commas in them in quotes.
    </p>
    <hr />
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="import" value="1" />
        <table cellpadding="4px">
            <tr>
                <td>CSV File: </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="csv" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MD5 Hash Passwords: </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="md5_passwords" /><br /><small>*Check this option if the passwords in your CSV are in plain text</small></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joomla Table Prefix: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="table_prefix" value="jos_" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joomla Database Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_schema" value="joomla" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MySQL Host: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_host" value="localhost" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MySQL Username: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_username" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MySQL Password: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mysql_password" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Import Users! " /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body></html>

    <?php

}

 function addJoomlaUser($name, $username, $password, $email, $defgroup) {




      jimport('joomla.user.helper');

      $data = array(
          "name"=>$name,
          "username"=>$username,
          "password"=>$password,
          "password2"=>$password,
          "email"=>$email,
          "block"=>0,
          "groups"=>array("1","2")
      );

      $user = new JUser;
      //Write to database
      if(!$user->bind($data)) {
          throw new Exception("Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError());
      }
      if (!$user->save()) {
          throw new Exception("Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError());
      }

  return $user->id;
}

function sql_prep($var) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
}

function display_user($message, $user) {

//  printf('<p>'.$message.'</p>');
    printf($message);
    printf('Name: "%s" ... ', sql_prep($user[0]));
    printf('  Username: "%s" ... ', sql_prep($user[1]));
    printf('  Password: "%s" ... ', sql_prep($user[3]));
    printf('  Mail: "%s" ... ', sql_prep($user[2]));
    printf('  Group: "%s" ', sql_prep($user[4]));
    printf('<br />');

    return;

}

?>
```